# Why is Composer unable to locate artisan when running the "composer install" command?

Tags: php, json, windows-7, laravel-4, composer-php

I am using windows 7 and trying to install laravel 4.2 using composer. My development environment is EasyPHP, but based on the research I have done, that is not the problem.

Every time I try to create a new laravel project, called "testapp", by running this command in my projects directory:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel testapp --prefer-dist
```

.., the installation is successful up until the point where composer tries to generate the "autoload" files, outputting these lines:

```
Generating autoload files
Could not open input file: artisan
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
Error Output:
```

If I then navigate to the new folder called testapp created in my projects directory, and run

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer install
```

I get the same error at the end.

Although composer doesn't seem to be able to run any php artisan command, by navigating to my testapp folder and running:

```
php artisan {any command here}
```

I can accomplish any artisan command I want.
After doing some research, I found that the problem is with composer itself. Composer does not know how to find the artisan file.
One suggestion was that I edit the composer.json file so that artisan would be defined by an absolute path rather than a relative path. So I changed this:

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
},
```

to this:

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\\data\\localweb\\projects\\testapp\\artisan clear-compiled",
            "php C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\\data\\localweb\\projects\\testapp\\artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\\data\\localweb\\projects\\testapp\\artisan clear-compiled",
            "php C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\\data\\localweb\\projects\\testapp\\artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\\data\\localweb\\projects\\testapp\\artisan key:generate"
        ]
},
```

within the composer.json file in my testapp folder. Now, when running

```
composer install
```

I got this output in the command prompt:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json.
You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Script php C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\proje
cts\testapp\artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned
with an error



[RuntimeException]
Error Output:



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p
lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver
bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Although I first thought that this output meant that changing the composer.json would not solve the problem, I was amazed to find that changing the composer.json worked when the absolute path **contained no spaces**.

For example. I went to C:\Users\AlexLeung\Desktop, ran

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel desktestapp --prefer-dist
```

got the initial error, then updated the composer.json in the new desktestapp folder to look like

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php C:\\Users\\AlexLeung\\Desktop\\desktestapp\\artisan clear-compiled",
            "php C:\\Users\\AlexLeung\\Desktop\\desktestapp\\artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php C:\\Users\\AlexLeung\\Desktop\\desktestapp\\artisan clear-compiled",
            "php C:\\Users\\AlexLeung\\Desktop\\desktestapp\\artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php C:\\Users\\AlexLeung\\Desktop\\desktestapp\\artisan key:generate"
        ]
},
```

, and running

```
composer install
```

was then successful. Although this shows I can install laravel if I just install it on a path with no spaces, I need to be able to install it in places under the "Program Files (x86)" directory since that is where EasyPHP, and its Apache web server root, are located. In trying to get the absolute path to work with spaces, I have tried using underscores, which ends up pointing to the wrong path, and \u0020, which generates the same error.

So the question remains:

**How can I get composer to recognize the artisan file within the newly created testapp folder?**

*A set of resulting questions if the first can't be answered:*
**1.** Is there a way to get composer to recognize the artisan file without me needing to change the composer.json to iunclude an absolute path for artisan?
**2.** Should I even be concerned about having the autoload files generated? (is it even necessary)
**3.** Would it be okay if I just moved my projects to the desktop (or any other path without spaces) anytime I needed to run composer update or install?

Overall I would like to have a complete installation of laravel and be able to use the convenient composer commands whenever I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your issue has to do with some kind of permissions because you are trying to run commands inside *"C:\Program Files (x86)"*. Try to deactivate UAC and see if that works.

Also try to run `php artisan clear-compiled` from the command line. It may not even be an issue with composer but with the PHP path. Verify that your Windows PATH variable knows where your `php.exe` is located.

I've just tested a clean install in a folder called *"C:\MyPrograms\Some kind of folder\"* and composer runs as expected, so it's may have nothing to do with spaces.

You can get composer to recognize php artisan, one way or another. My personal experience tells me that having developer tools installed in *C:\Program Files* is not a good idea because you will keep getting unexpected behaviors. I advice you to instal PHP, Apache, EasyPHP & whatever you need in a new folder (like *"C:\MyPrograms"*).

Anyhow, even if you have PHP and Apache installed in the default program files folder, you can always set your Document Root of Apache to another location and this may also solve your issue.

As for your other questions:

2) Yes, it really is necessary. The autoload files (will be located in `vendor/composer/`) enable you to work with namespaces and to work with your own classes and never to `include()` or `require()` because it will be done by Laravel automatically.

3) I guess you could do that and it will work. But the hassle of moving your entire project every time you need a composer update seems to much trouble and wasted time.

Comment: It looks like i'll be installing EasyPHP to a different location

Answer (score 0):

I think you found a bug in Composer.

This line probably is supposed to make the commands used in the hooks executable:

https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/a8adbfeb9fc7861deade782938222714168a22a8/src/Composer/Command/RunScriptCommand.php#L89

I suspect that the result of `realpath()` with the binary directory will return the correct path, but including spaces. `putenv()` looks like operating directly on the shell, with it's parameter being `"PATH=C:\Path with spaces\somewhere;C:\PreviousPaths\"` - this might not be working on Windows.

You should add an issue on Github to get this fixed.

From experience, lots of software is not well prepared to deal with spaces in paths. I recently had to rename all my Jenkins job names because "job name === workspace directory name", and the backup module was acting up on the spaces.

Comment: This is a pretty annoying bug. I guess I have learned not to put software in paths with spaces.